# Android widgets and variables should not be reassigned

Tags: java, android, lint

Sonar Lint points out I should introduce a new variable instead of reusing the parameter.

in my extendedListView adapter I have

```
 @Override
  public View getGroupView(... , View convertView , ...){
     if(convertView == null){
         // gets the layoutInflater
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, parent, false);
     }
     // then all the fill the list with data stuff
     return convertView;

  }
```

Sonar makes a good point and I thought I should do something else but i do not know what can be done in this situation. I need to check if the convertView is null or I'll replace it every time, but at the same time the error makes sense in any standard java code just not here inside the widget to me. How would I fix this ?

Comment: Reassigning the variable is not replacing it! You're just reassigning the pointer to it, that's why it's warning you

Comment: I vaguely remember this was a code smell in java since compiler doesnt check it and at runtime you could have a NPE, in this case it would crash the app if it was returning a null

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't see anything wrong with your current code. If you want to avoid that warning, however, you can pretend your method args are *final* and do the following...

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(... , View convertView , ...){
  View myView = convertView;
  if(myView == null){
    // gets the layoutInflater
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, parent, false);
  }
  // then all the fill the list with data stuff
  return myView;
}
```

Your linter is marking something that is in the realm of code styling. PMD also marks code in similar scenarios. Usually, I'd expect a `getView(...)` method to be very concise so I wouldn't expect the reuse of the variable to cause any confusion.